# Python 3.5.2 - shutil.copy2 OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python

I am randomly getting this error when using `shutil.copy2` to copy a large file. The copy process is started, and the error is returned during the copy operation. Is this library unstable for python 3, are there better solutions for copying large files?

Code is simple: `shutil.copy2(source_path, destination_path)`

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tests\Tests.py", line 24, in test_copy_large_file
    shutil.copy2(large_file_path, destination_path)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 116, in copyfile
    copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 76, in copyfileobj
    fdst.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Is there enough diskspace left to copy the file?

Comment: Yes, I am copying it on a NAS device with a large storage space